# Which one is racetrack? Isn't it a holding over VOR on the left and holding over FIX on the right?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, approach, ils, holding, jeppesen

Which one is a racetrack? Isn't it a holding over VOR on the left and holding over FIX on the right? If one of them is a racetrack, how is it different from holding? Or are they both used in the same way on this chart? Because MHA is given for both symbols, so it is certain that they are holdings, isn't it? In addition, one symbol is thick and the other is a thin line. This picture is taken from page 11-2 of the LTBR Jeppesen chart (ILS Y or LOC Y Rwy 25R).

[image]

Comment: The BOLD hold at KESEV is the required course reversal prior to the final approach. The lighter line hold at BRY is part of the missed approach -- after the procedure has been attempted unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they didn’t disambiguate between the two in comment (3) because it doesn’t matter, 230 is the published max for both.

*Both* are holds, and *both* could be called “racetracks”…  The reason for the bold line is that KESEV hold is an expected, integral part of the approach procedure.  There are legal/procedural differences that occur *once established on a published approach segment*, and the bold line denotes that the KESEV hold *is* an approach segment.